# Import Excel SpreadSheet To Array

Tags: c#, arrays, excel-2007

I found the below syntax to import the 1st column of my Excel Spreadsheet into an array.  The code works excellent and is very short and precise!  The issue I have is I need to skip the 1st row in the column as that is header information, how can I skip the 1st row with the below syntax?

```
Workbook wb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename);
Sheets sheets = wb.Worksheets;
Worksheets ws = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
Range firstColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns[1];
System.Array myValues = (System.Array)firstColumn.Cells.Value;
string[] list = myvalues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] list = myvalues.OfType<object>()
                        .Skip(1)
                        .Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
```